# Regex with negative lookahead still matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying to test for a shebang "#!" to see if it doesn't have a forward slash on either side with this regex `(?!\/)#\!(?!\/)`

It should match:
`#!`, `z#!`, `#!z`,  `z#!z`

It should **not** match: `/#!`, `#!/`, `/#!/`

I put negative lookaheads around the shebang so it won't match any slashes, and indeed it doesn't match trailing slashes, but for some reason it is still matching leading slashes `/#!`.

***[example on regexr](http://regexr.com/39f2b)***

Any ideas on why this is happening / how to fix it?

Comment: Your first lookahead should be a lookbehind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a combination of [**Negative Lookbehind** and **Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds).

```
(?<!/)#!(?!/)
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<!     # look behind to see if there is not:
  /      #   '/'
)        # end of look-behind
#!       # '#!'
(?!      # look ahead to see if there is not:
  /      #   '/'
)        # end of look-ahead
```